# Difference between Enplug SDK web extension URLs?

Tags: enplug-sdk

I'm using the [Enplug SDK](https://developers.enplug.com) web extension to create an app to show digital menus from [DSMenu](http://dsmenu.com) on screens using Enplug. I'm using AngularJS on my config page.

I'm confused about the relationship between the "Configure Url" setting in the back-end from [this guide](https://developers.enplug.com/guides/building-web-page-app-extension/), and the `Value.Url` in the payload from [this tutorial](https://developers.enplug.com/guides/web-page-extension-tutorial/).

**Configure URL**

[image: Configure Enplug app]

**Value.Url**

```
$scope.page = {
    Value: {
        ShowContent: 'url', // Show Content is used to hide/show the Url or Html form field based on the selection.
        Url: '', // The Url the web page back-end uses to display the content.
        Html: '', // If applicable, used to show custom HTML. Cannot be used in conjunction with the Url.
        ShowMobileWebsite: false, //Only applies if OverrideUserAgent is true, False = Show Desktop Website, True = Show Mobile Website
        OverrideUserAgent: false, //False = Use android's best fit. True = Use the value of ShowMobileWebsite
        ShowDelay: 0, //Custom delay between displaying the page after it's been loaded.
        RefreshInterval: 0, // Custom refresh interval rate in X seconds.
        AllowJavascript: true, // Set to true by default, allows Javascript to be executed on the page.
        Username: '', // Username option, would need to write script passing in credentials.
        Password: '', // Password option, would need to write script passing in credentials.
        Token: '', // Token option, would need to wrtie script passing in credentials.
        JavascriptOnload: '' // Custom JS to be executed once the page loads, can be used to log into authenticated pages.
    }
};
```

I created a page http://www.dsmenu.com/con-enplug-display.php and each app will have a custom URL to show the menu like http://www.dsmenu.com/uph/204. Where do I put each?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'Configure Url' is the link to the configuration page which will be displayed to the end user on Enplugs web dashboard, in your example  http://www.dsmenu.com/con-enplug-display.php

The Value.Url is the link to the web app that will be shown publicly on the screen in the venue. In your case http://www.dsmenu.com/uph/204